# Read Video File using File Reader in JavaScript

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-addin, jsom

I am using below code to upload video file in SharePoint Online video library.

```
function RequestExecutorLoad(){
    var context;
    var factory;
    var appContextSite;
    context = new SP.ClientContext(appWebUrl);
    factory = new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(appWebUrl);
    context.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);
    appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostWebUrl);
    var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appWebUrl);
    executor.executeAsync(
       {
          url: uploadUrl,
          method: "POST",                
          data: videoFileData,
          processData: false,
          headers: {
               "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
               "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
               "content-length": videoFileData.byteLength
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("Success! Your video was uploaded to Sharepoint " + videoDestination + ".");                    
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(err));                    
            }
            console.log("Video failed to upload to library");
    }
```

}

```
function FileReaderOfVideo() {
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = function (readerEvt) {
   var fileData = '';        
   videoFileData = readerEvt;
   console.log('Video file data is read.');
   RequestExecutorLoad();    
   };
   reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
```

**It is uploading file as image content type.** Am i missing anything? I need to upload video. any help is useful to get my result.